# Windows 7 security center notification problem with Kaspersky 2011

Tags: windows-7, kaspersky

I just got a problem: Windows 7 security center shows that I haven't installed any antivirus, even though I am using Kaspersky 2011 Internet Security. It's also not detecting the firewall of Kaspersky. This was changed by some security update I installed few days ago.

How can I fix this?

Comment: OT: Kaspersky has the worst firwall, windows7 is the safest

Comment: But the problem is not about kaspersky ...it is about windows 7 notification problem

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall kaspersky

Comment: no their is some win7 problem but I dont know what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Frozenking:- I solved this problem by switching off security notifications of antivirus and firewall from control panel-> action centre; now its ok

Answer (score 3):

The only way "you" can fix this is contacting Kaspersky support. They have to release a new version which fixes the problem.

Comment: srry dude but I dont think it is about kaspersky i recently installed updates from win7 after that problem began..but I dont know shich update might have cause this problem.

Comment: @FrozenKing The Windows updates that were installed may have set some things back to default in Windows, reinstalling Kaspersky may re-register it as your antivirus product.  At least try a repair install of Kaspersky.